# D2L Valence: Retrieve Final Grades

Tags: desire2learn, valence

Is there a way to get both the Final Calculated Grade and the Final Adjusted Grade? I would like to be able to compare them.

Comment: Valence is the API...

Comment: Technically speaking 'Valence' is the brand-name for Desire2Learn's extensibility developer platform: the Learning Framework APIs are the collections of REST-like web service APIs that a client can use to make remote functional calls of a back-end service (the LMS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the best solution (or workaround) is to retrieve the final grade, determine what column it's coming from, and then subtract or add (+1 / -1) to the objectID to get the corresponding Calculated or Adjusted column.

Comment: Please note that this is a fragile workaround. Grade column IDs (like most D2L integer-based IDs) are allocated at creation time, and persist with the column. If a column is moved or deleted, then this can obviously mess up notions about functional adjacency corresponding with adjacency in the ID name space. Also, please note that D2L ID values are intended to be opaque, in the sense that just because they're incrementing numerical values _today_ is _no guarantee at all_ that they'll be incrementing numerical values going forward.

Comment: I completely agree. This is definitely not the way I would like to solve this problem. I would expect that D2L would provide this type of functionality as part of the standard set of calls. Until that's developed, I don't have much choice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering:

GET /d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitId)/grades/values/(userId)/

Retrieve all the grade objects for a particular user assigned in an org unit.

Return. This action returns a JSON array of GradeValue blocks.

Grade.GradeValue{

```
"DisplayedGrade": <string>,
"GradeObjectIdentifier": <string:D2LID>,
"GradeObjectName": <string>,
"GradeObjectType": <number:GRADEOBJ_T>,
"GradeObjectTypeName": <string>|null,
"PointsNumerator": <number>|null,
"PointsDenominator": <number>|null,
"WeightedDenominator": <number>|null,
"WeightedNumerator": <number>|null
```

}

and then look at the "GradeObjectType" for "7" or "8"?

### Grade object type / Value

FinalCalculated  / 7 ^

FinalAdjusted    / 8 ^

(I wonder what is meant by "^ Direct creation of these types through these APIs is not supported.")

Comment: I wish it was that easy. The regular GET calls for Grade.GradeValue does not return the final grade. You have to use the final grade calls to get the final grade but you can only get one, not both.

Comment: Are you saying the **GET* for **Grade.GradeValue{...}** where GradeObjectType is either "7" or "8" returns NULL? ...

Ewww...

Comment: Not exactly, GET does not return the values of 7 or 8 at all unless you use the final grade GET calls.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there currently is no way to retrieve the final adjusted grade value through the Valence Learning Framework API, only the final calculated grade value. Additionally, end-user type callers can only see the final grade when the grade gets released: up until that point, only users capable of setting a final grade value (or perhaps releasing it?) can see the final grade value for a user.

Comment: Is this on the roadmap?

Comment: Typically, Desire2Learn doesn't speak to the roadmap around particular bits of functionality; overall, they have a continued commitment to the Valence extensibility platform. If you'd like to lobby for this particular enhancement, you're quite welcome to communicate that wish through your account or partner manager, or by visiting the Product Idea Exchange in the D2L Community site, and presenting your request there (or voting for another client's request if it matches your needs as well).