# Final adjusted grade Valence

Tags: valence

Is there a way through the valence API's to pull the Final adjusted grade? I have tried to make calls via
GET  /d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitId)/grades/final/values/(userId)

and via

GET /d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitId)/grades/values/(userId)/

but have failed to get the final adjusted grade values for the user.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*"I have not seen a way to force it with valence"*

Awww....

*"You half to configure the system to export the final adjusted grade instead of the calculated grade. This is done with the d2l user interface in the gradebooks options"*

You also have to get the teachers to remember to set up their gradebook that way, and to transfer the Calculated values to Adjusted Grade results within the gradebook. Some of them will forget to do so.

Don't forget, those Valence calls for *"/grades/final/values/"* are **pre-release**. In other words, it's quite possible (using Valence API) to retrieve the calculated/adjusted values before the teacher has officially "released" them for students to view. In short, your Valence calls may be a bit premature.

What seems to be missing in Valence is a call for

**"Get Final Released Grade"** - the same value the student would see (when it's been released).

The decision for Calculated Vs Adjusted would have already been made by the teacher (in the process of releasing the grades), and no results returned from the call (ie: a 404 error) until the teacher releases those grades.

I wonder if there's already a Valence API feature request for that?

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a thought.

To get around the problem of fetching grades before the teacher releases them...

... something Victor Haag (from D2L) said in in this thread

[D2L Valence: Retrieve Final Grades](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293428/d2l-valence-retrieve-final-grades)

*"Additionally, end-user type callers can only see the final grade when the grade gets released"*

So I'm wondering if it's possible - for a downstream system (like a Student Management System harvesting grades from the Brightspace LMS, perhaps triggered by dates) to **impersonate** the student as the *"Current user context"*.

GET /d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitId)/grades/final/values/myGradeValue

If the Student Management System making these Valence webservice calls (pretending to be a student with grades) gets a **404** error, the grades haven't been released yet by the teacher.

I don't yet know if it's possible for a "system account" to impersonate a user for the *"Current user context"*

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11223918)

Comment: fair enough, but it was simply a radical idea to try and solve the initial problem.

Comment: I've just found out that it is **impossible**, using the Valence API, **to impersonate another user**.

https://community.brightspace.com/devcop/f_technical/impersonated_users_through_api

_"It's not possible to impersonate a user in the first place from the Valence APIs, so there's no way to check if a user is being impersonated."_

so that means the "creative" idea to impersonate the user to then use the "myGradeValue" calls to get the official "released" grade (whether calculated or adjusted) ...

**... won't work.**

Sorry for the red-herring, it could have been a cool work-around.

Answer (score -1):

This action is the correct one,
GET /d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitId)/grades/final/values/(userId)

I have not seen a way to force it with valence. You half to configure the system to export the final adjusted grade instead of the calculated grade. This is done with the d2l user interface in the gradebooks options. It is the same option for when exporting the gradebook's final grade to a file with the web interface.